# How to change Horizontal div to vertical with divs order change using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 divs ex. A,B, C, D on horizontally, how to display those divs A,C next line then B, D on Mobile View using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `flex` ordering

below are the example

```css
ul{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
ul li:nth-child(1){
  order: 1;
}
ul li:nth-child(2){
  order: 3;
}

ul li:nth-child(3){
 order: 2;
}

ul li:nth-child(4){
 order: 4;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>A</li>
 <li>B</li>
 <li>C</li>
 <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

For mobile you can use width to show item side by side or below each other.

Answer (score 0):

col-xs-6 class to divs.Read oficial docs for more informatioms and break points.

Comment: Need to change order like A, C, B, D. instead A, B, C, D.

Comment: maybe flexbox order can help you try searching that on google.You will probably need to wrap divs

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4?

For 3 you might want to check out the push/pull classes - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering

In version 4 this is replaced by ordering - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering